# Задать setVisibility всем ImageView в RecyclerView. Вызов метода адаптера из активити

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть разметка для элементов RecyclerView с ImageView, по зажатию которой можно перемещать элементы внутри RV (Drag&Drop). По умолчанию видимость IV установлена GONE, но по клику пункта в меню тулбара моего экрана активити необходимо задать VISIBLE всем необходимым ImageView'хам, что бы было видно за что перетаскивать элементы RV.

Собственно, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать метод, который будет задавать видимость вьюхам в адаптере, и, самое главное, как вызвать этот метод в моей активити

**Разметка элемента RV**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/rv_card"
        style="@style/MainCardStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/station_logo"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/avtoradio_logo"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/station_name"
                    style="@style/MainTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Европа плюс"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_nav"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/station_freq"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="105,3 FM"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_card_small_text_color"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
            </LinearLayout>


        // Этому ImageView необходимо задать видимость
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dragView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="13dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_drag_album"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public static class StationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        CardView cardView;
        TextView stationName;
        TextView stationFrequency;
        ImageView stationLogo;
        ImageView dragView;

        StationViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            final Context context = itemView.getContext();
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_card);
            stationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_name);
            stationFrequency = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_freq);
            stationLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_logo);
            dragView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dragView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                setAlbumRV();
                break;
            case 2:
                setListRV();
                break;
            case R.id.changeItemPositions:
            //Вот тут необходимо сделать видимыми все вьюхи
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final StationViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.stationName.setText(stationsModelList.get(i).name);
        holder.stationFrequency.setText(stationsModelList.get(i).frequency);
        holder.stationLogo.setImageResource(stationsModelList.get(i).logo);
        holder.dragView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) ==
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) ==
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    onDragStartListener.onDragStarted(holder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: а где `onBindViewHolder()`? в общем то нужен только он ...

Comment: @pavlofff упс, добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку кода адаптера в вопросе нет, приведу абстрактный пример (только важные части адаптера):

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.StationViewHolder> {
    private boolean isImageVisible;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StationViewHolder holder, int i) {

        holder.dragView.setVisibility(isImageVisible? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE));
    }

    public void setImageVisible (boolean isVisible){

      isImageVisible = isVisible;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

   public void changeVisiblity (){

      isImageVisible = !isImageVisible;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

из активити вызываете метод адаптера:

```
adapter.setImageVisible (true); // показать кнопки
adapter.setImageVisible (false); // скрыть кнопки
```

переключение в методе меню:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.changeItemPositions:
          adapter.changeVisiblity();
          break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Шикарно! То, что надо. Спасибо)

Comment: @Haze дополнил переключение из активити еще отдельным методом